# Build error trying to create a method to handle parameters of multiple object types

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this instance method where I am trying to generalize the last statement to handle multiple object classes :

```
-(void)showHTMLHelp:(NSString *)htmlString pointTo:(id)target background:(UIColor *)bgColor
```

where I don't know what class the target object is until runtime.  This is the code to do the checking (2nd statement is causing the build error):

```
    if([target isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]])
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:(UITextField)&target.frame inView:self.view
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

This is the build error:

> Property 'frame' not found on object of type '__strong id'

Why?  I have a cast to the correct class and all of the *targets* have actual "frames" (UITableView, UITextField and UITextView).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if([target isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]])
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:((UITextField *)target).frame inView:self.view
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your target doesn't have an actual frame (origin x, origin y, width, height), you cannot presentPopoverFromRect because it doesn't know where to pop out from.
Try

```
if([target isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]])
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect::CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) inView:self.view
                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Where your CGRectMake is your (origin x, origin y, width, height)

Comment: That won't work because the "target" is where the popover arrow points... All of the targets have actual "frames" (UITableView, UITYextyField and UITextView).